# Neural Network for regression should I use relu or linear function for output node?

Tags: regression, neural-networks, multiple-regression, nonlinear-regression

I am using TensorFlow to build a Neural Network for regression. Here is a MWE code:

**MWE on Linnerud Dataset**

```py
    ######################### import stuff ##########################
    from math import sqrt
    import numpy as np
    import pandas as pd
    import tensorflow as tf
    from sklearn.datasets import load_linnerud
    from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

    ######################## prepare the data ########################
    X, y = load_linnerud(return_X_y=True)
    X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.33, shuffle=False)   

    ######################## set learning variables ##################
    learning_rate = 0.001 
    epochs = 5000
    batch_size = 3    

    ######################## set some variables #######################
    x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 3], name='x')  # 3 features
    y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 3], name='y')  # 3 outputs

    # input-to-hidden layer1
    W1 = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([3, 10], stddev=0.03), name='W1')
    b1 = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([10]), name='b1')

    # hidden layer 1-to-output
    W2 = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([10, 3], stddev=0.03), name='W2')
    b2 = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([3]), name='b2')

    ######################## Activations, outputs ######################
    # output hidden layer 1
    hidden_out = tf.nn.relu(tf.add(tf.matmul(x, W1), b1))   #standard    

    # total output
    y_ = tf.nn.relu(tf.add(tf.matmul(hidden_out, W2), b2))    

    ####################### Loss Function  #########################
    mse = tf.losses.mean_squared_error(y, y_)

    ####################### Optimizer      #########################
    optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate=learning_rate).minimize(mse)

    ###################### Initialize, Accuracy and Run #################
    # initialize variables
    init_op = tf.global_variables_initializer()

    # run
    with tf.Session() as sess:
      sess.run(init_op)
      total_batch = int(len(y_train) / batch_size)
      for epoch in range(epochs):
        avg_cost = 0
        for i in range(total_batch):
          batch_x, batch_y = X_train[i * batch_size:min(i * batch_size + batch_size, len(X_train)), :], \
                             y_train[i * batch_size:min(i * batch_size + batch_size, len(y_train)), :]
          _, c = sess.run([optimizer, mse], feed_dict={x: batch_x, y: batch_y})
          avg_cost += c / total_batch
        if epoch % 500 == 0:
          print('Epoch:', (epoch + 1), 'cost =', '{:.3f}'.format(avg_cost))
      print(sqrt(sess.run(mse, feed_dict={x: X_test, y: y_test})))
      ypred = sess.run(y_, feed_dict = {x: X_test})
```

However, it is not quite clear whether it is correct to use `relu` also as an activation function for the output node. Some people say that using just a linear transformation would be better since we are doing regression. Other people say it should ALWAYS be relu in all the layers.

So what should I do? Here I used `relu` in the hidden layer and in the output layer.

In case I need to use the linear function, do you also know how I can do that in TensorFlow?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Relu in the last layer looks strange. Maybe it could make sense if the variable you are trying to predict is non-negative.

Otherwise simply remove `tf.nn.relu` call in the `y_ = ...` line. The part `tf.add(tf.matmul(hidden_out, W2), b2)` *is* the linear function you are looking for.

Comment: Interesting idea to use an activation function on the output layer to deal with non-negative variables...  I had been contemplating an integration of e.g. Tweedie or Gamma GLMs with neural nets, but this seems way simpler.  Have you ever tried it?

Comment: No, and have not seen it anywhere either, so possibly it does not work well...

Comment: @psarka thank you a lot! It looked strange indeed! From what I understand the Neural Network is like a linear regression applied to a transformation of the input. So the relu didn't make sense!

Can I ask you if you also think the code is good? I couldn't find anywhere some good code showing a ANN for regression

Comment: @Euler_Salter looks all right. You can also consider trying Keras, it is less tedious, so you can focus more on the concepts, and experiment fast.

Comment: ReLU on output layer to get non-negative outputs does not sound like the idea, using something like exp is more common choice.